# How to tag twitter list in post/tweet?

Tags: java, twitter, social-networking, twitter4j, twitter-rest-api

I am using twitter list api to add people in the list(List Name: New People), it will be used as target people. When I add a user to my public list they get notified, twitter feature.

Now as per their documentation :

https://support.twitter.com/articles/20169276

*You can link to any Twitter list by mentioning it as you would any Twitter account, simply add a forward slash ("/") between the username and list name. For example, to mention @Support and link to a list called “Tips”, type: @Support/Tips.*

above mentioning criteria is not working for me.

now my question is, how can I tweet for a single list ? which means only added members can see that post not others? or to be more precise how to tweet for a particular set of members

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I tweet for a single list ? which means only added members can see that post not others?

You need to create a private account and only accept follow requests from members of the list.

That's the only way to post a message on Twitter and only have it seen by a select group.

Comment: Thanks Eden, but a single account could have multiple list and a list could have multiple users then again If I tweet something would it notify each and every member or particular list. I am looking for how to tweet for a particular set of members

Comment: There is no option in Twitter to do that, sorry.